# Case use with нету

Tags: грамматика

Всем привет) I have read a previous post about the use of нету and it's meaning. In this opportunity I would like to know which is the case that the adjacent subject must have. 
For example, how would you say: "There is no dog." Which case would you use?

Comment: Note that what is adjacent ('dog') is not the subject in such Russian sentences with нет/нету, they are impersonal sentences and have no subjects. And also, remember, there's absolutely no need to ask about the case of the subject, in Russian it is always Nominative.

Comment: Oh you're right, my mistake. In this case I should have asked for the object's case.

Comment: Hehe, no, it's not an object either. It's the predicative.

Comment: Also please keep in mind, that _нету_ is informal. The grammatically right variant is to use _нет_: «Нет собаки.» (There is no dog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Genitive: нету собаки; same as нет (in the "there is no" sense) and ни. The colloquial (and getting normative acceptance) tendency to drop the negative genitive in favour of accusative doesn't apply here; that only happens to objects of transitive verbs.